# CSS @Media Print - horizontal spacing of inline elements

Tags: css, angularjs, printing, media

Hi have been working on an AngularJS POS system what needs to print receipts after making a sale.  I display a sales summary and use ng-print to print the div containing the sales summary.  I do the usual with display:none for all other elements and then the rest is display:block.  There are a some rows that need to print in a line so I set them to inline but I cannot get spacing between these or even align.

This is an image of the sales summary and the spacing for Desc, Price and Qty.
[image]

Here is the html for this:

```
<div id="sales-summary">
                <div layout="column" class="sales-summary-headers" style="text-align: center" style="margin: 3px">
                    <div class="print-address">{{transaction.store.name}}</div>
                    <div class="print-address">{{transaction.store.address1}}</div>
                    <div class="print-address">{{transaction.store.address2}}</div>
                    <div class="print-address">{{transaction.store.address3}}</div>
                    <div class="print-address">{{transaction.store.contact}}</div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="print-address">You were served by: {{transaction.employee.firstName}}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="sales-summary-headers">
                    <div style="text-align: center"> Sales Summary</div>    
                </div>
                <md-divider></md-divider>
                <div layout="row" class="print-row">
                    <div class="print-left" flex="65"><p>Desc</p></div>
                    <div class="print-mid" flex="15"><p>Qty</p></div>
                    <div class="print-right" layout-align="center end"><p>Price</p></div>
                </div>
                <md-divider></md-divider>
                <div layout="row" class="print-row" ng-repeat="item in saleItems">
                    <div class="print-left" flex="65">{{item.product.description}} </div>
                    <div class="print-mid" flex="15">{{item.quantity}} </div>
                    <div class="print-right" layout-align="center end">{{item.unitTotalDisplayPrice | currency:"€"}} </div>
                    <br/>
                </div>
                <md-divider></md-divider>
                <md-divider></md-divider>
                <div layout="row" class="print-row">
                    <div flex="80">Subtotal</div>
                    <div layout-align="center end">{{ subTotal | currency:"€" }}</div>
                </div>
                <div layout="row" class="print-row">
                    <div flex="80">Tax</div>
                    <div layout-align="center end">{{ tax | currency:"€" }}</div>
                </div>
                <div layout="row" class="print-row">
                    <div flex="80">Total</div>
                    <div layout-align="center end">{{ total | currency:"€" }}</div>
                </div>
                <md-divider></md-divider>
                <div style="text-align: center" class="sales-summary-headers">
                    <div>Payments</div> 
                </div>
                <md-divider></md-divider>
                <div layout="row" class="print-row" ng-repeat="payment in payments">
                    <div flex="80">{{ payment.type }}</div>
                    <div layout-align="center end">{{ payment.amount | currency:"€" }}</div>
                    <br/>
                </div>
                <md-divider></md-divider>
                <div layout="row" class="print-row">
                    <div flex="80">Change</div>
                    <div layout-align="center end">{{ transaction.changeValue | currency:"€"}}</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        Some message for the store...
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div class="print-row" style="text-align: center" style="margin: 3px">
                    <h4>Till: {{ transaction.till.name }}</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div layout="row" >
                  <md-button ng-print print-element-id="sales-summary">
               Print
              </md-button>
              <md-button ng-click="email()">
               Email
              </md-button>
              <span flex></span>
              <md-button ng-click="finishTransaction()" >
               Done
              </md-button>
    </div>
```

It prints only the elements within id="sales-summary".

I have tried to set spacing in CSS but nothing works
Here is code of the CSS.  It is a little dirty as I have added in background colors and text color to try isolate elements and see what space the take up on the print preview.

```
@media print {
body * {
    display:none;
}

md-sidenav * {
    display: none !important;
}

section  * {
    display: none !important;
}

#printSection, #printSection * {
    display: block;
}

#printSection {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    top:0;
}
.print-row *{
    width:100%;
    display: inline !important;
    color: green;
    /*background-color: pink;*/
    margin: 2px;
}

.print-row div *{
    display: inline !important;
}



.print-left{
    text-align: left;
    width:65% !important;
    background-color: blue;
    color: black;
}

.print-mid p{

    width:65% !important;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}

.print-row{
    background-color: yellow;
    width:100% !important;
    /*font-size: 0pt;*/
}

.print-left{
    text-align: left;
    width:65% !important;
    /*font-size: 12pt;*/
}

.print-mid{
    width:15% !important;
    text-align: right;
    /*font-size: 12pt;*/
}

.print-right{
    width:20% !important;
    text-align: right !important;
    /*font-size: 12pt;*/
}
```

Here is what prints.  No spacing between the desc, Qty Price.
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is the rule with this selector:

```
.print-row *{
```

It defines all these elements as inline elements, by which their `width` setting becomes meaningless. Try to set this to `inline-block`